# Taxonomy image div background

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to set the taxonomy image url in div style background (xxxxx). I use "taxonomy images" plugin but `wp_get_attachment_image` doesn't work.

```
<?php
$terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array(
        'taxonomy'     => 'categoria_proyectos',
    ));

if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
    print '';
    foreach ( (array) $terms as $term ) {
        print '
        <a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term, $term->taxonomy ) ) . '">
        <div class="style="background-image: url(xxxxxx); ">
        </div>
        </a>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to get url of attached featured image .

`<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID(), array('700', '600'), "", array( "class" => "img-responsive" ) );  ?>`